# Reverse a Integer Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am looking for an easy way to reverse an integer in erlang. Example: 1234 to 4321.

Comment: If it's homework, please add the proper tag.

Comment: If its not homework should I add the proper not-homework tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use some of the built in functions to do this easily.

```
1> list_to_integer(lists:reverse(integer_to_list(1234))).
4321
```